Server not booting after reboot
I have had a HP server running in my home for a number of years, just acting as a smb share for the most part. Recently, the share had stopped working, restarting the service had got it working, but always seemed to stop. Today, I couldn't access it, restarted the service, checked the firewalls, checked the config and tcpdumped to make sure it was responding, but still not working.
I went with rebooting the device as my next step, no response. Checking the cli, after another hard reboot, it doesn't seem to get passed
[ OK ] Mounted /boot.
enter image description here
With it stalled at this point, does this indicate an issue with that location or any next steps I should follow. I have a feeling that it's fairly old version, something like 16...

ok, so turned out i just needed to leave it longer as it's responding to icmp and can ssh, no smb working, but at least it's back.
